# How to make the font size smaller when I resize the browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am making a website with html5 and css. I am trying to make this website responsive, but I don't know why the size of the font stay the same when I resize the browser window, even when I'm using `em` or `percentage`s such as: `font-size: XXem` or `font-size: XX%`.

How can I make font resizable?

Answer (score 61):

For HTML5 web pages I would highly suggest using Viewpoint Width/Height values. They function similarly to % but are font sizes that resize with the window.

For example...

```
.some-paragraph{
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

This would set the font-size to always be 5% of the current viewport width, even on re-sizing!

Learn more here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Note: You may need to have this in your head:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Very nice trick @victor3y I used it in my project, and it works like a charm.
I had to design a table to be viewed on different cell phones. And by using vh measurement for fonts, I was able to deal with all of those screens with just one media query for that particular table.

Comment: First I've heard about this, but it actually works in my table. I told our html challenged editor that I don't really recommend it, because line-breaks are a normal behavior when you shrink your browser. But if she thinks this is some kind of magical trick, then I can move on to the next complaint.

Answer (score 11):

It's called Responsive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
your font  style goes here

}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
 your font  style goes here

}


@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 your font  style goes here


}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 your font  style goes here

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your media queries, they should be controlling your font size, if you're using responsive techniques.

A code sample would help.

Give rem a shot. Works better than % or em.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to style based on a range of screen ratios and specifications, but here's an example using both rem units and jQuery to make the font smaller when you resize the browser width. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/rv22g/3/).

CSS

```
html { font-size: 90.5%; }
body { font-size: 1.4rem;}
h1 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var holdWidth = $(window).width();
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        newPercentage = (($(window).width() / holdWidth) * 100) + "%";
        $("html").css("font-size", newPercentage)
    });
});
```

and [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/rv22g/4/) averaging both the width and height for the new font size percentage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var holdWidth = $(window).width();
    var holdHeight = $(window).height();
    var holdAverageSize = (holdWidth + holdHeight) / 2;
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        newAverageSize = ($(window).width() + $(window).height()) / 2;
        newPercentage = ((newAverageSize / holdAverageSize) * 100) + "%";
        $("html").css("font-size", newPercentage)
        console.log(newPercentage);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.text {
    font-size: 50px;
}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 300px)
and (max-width : 500px) {

   .text {
    font-size: 20px;
   }

}

    @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 500px)
    and (max-width : 800px) {

       .text {
        font-size: 30px;
       }

    }

</style>


<div class="text">Test Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this by using @media query's and a viewport in your css , and add this meta tag to your html:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0”>
```

and with the @media query's and viewport you declare what size you have per screen width using this media query + viewport in css:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 820px) and (max-width: 920px) {
  @viewport { width: 820px; }   

            // your css for screens between 820 and 920 pixels in width goes here

  }
```

i mostly use the value's : from 20 - 600 , 600-700 , 700-820 , 820 - 920 , 920 - 1200,   @media screen and (min-width: 1200px){  @viewport { width: 1200px; }(this last one will set the size for any screen bigger than 1200 px in width so  your code for the biggest version goeds here}

So this means you will have 6 times your css code which is adapted will be adapted to the size.

This is called adaptive or responsive design and is pretty easy to do

For more info you might check this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Responsively adjusts the text size, according to the window size, but keeps it just large enough for mobile compatibility
http://typecast.com/blog/a-more-modern-scale-for-web-typography

Answer (score 1):

**font-size: 25vmin;**

This was very good resizing font in both height and width. 
You dont need anything in the head.

Answer (score 0):

How are you specifying your baseline font-size (against your html or body tags in your CSS file)? If you're setting this value to a pixel (or other fixed measure) or inheriting a browser default font size your percentage or em values will always be a percentage of these defaults.

The most common approach to building responsive sites is to do a 'mobile first' approach whereby your default style sheet handles the base styling for your site on a small screen, then use media queries in CSS to tweak the styles as screen size increases. Are you using any media queries/breakpoints currently?